# Enable Javascript Intellisense for a class instance with XML comment

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

How can I tell Visual Studio 2010 to recognise my variable as an instance of a given class?

```
var myObjCls = function() {
    this.Hello = "World";
};

var anotherObjCls = function (myObj) {
    /// <param name="myObj" type="myObjCls"></param>

    myObj. // Hello is NOT available

    var myObjLocal = new myObjCls();
    myObjLocal. // Hello is available

}
```

So my param XML doc is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define a proper constructor (Class is not the right term) like this...

```
function MyObject() {
  this.hello = "World";
}
```

The convention is to use Pascal casing or [UpperCamelCase](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for constructors and Camel casing for variables, functions, etc.

The next step is to create an instance using this constructor.

```
var myObj = new MyObject();
console.log(myObj.hello)
```

I didn't test it in Visual Studio, but I'm sure if you follow the JS conventions VS will understand what you're doing.